# java command not found Paramiko

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a .sh file using paramiko. with this code:

```
import paramiko

cmd = "cd path ; ./ file.sh"

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(server,username.password)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
print stdout.readlines()
ssh.close()
```

but I got this error:
java command not found.

file is passing parameters to loadtestrunner.sh and the error is refering to a line in loadtest runner which is:

```
java $JAVA_OPTS -cp $SOAPUI_CLASSPATH com.eviware.soapui.SoapUIProLoadTestRunner "$@"
```

java is installed on server. and loadtestrunner succesfuly runs directly from server

Answer (score 0):

You may have some shell profile that loads java into PATH. If not, create one. Mine is ~/.bash_profile and it contains the line `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_21/bin`.

Simply append `source ~./bash_profile \n` to your command and you should be able to use java from paramiko's ssh. (Note that your profile my be ~/.bashrc or a non-bash alternative)